# upload progress statistics using AWS S3 createMultipartUpload (AWS PHP SDK v3)

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3, file-upload

## Problem

Currently I'm using the AWS S3 createMultipartUpload function to upload large files (videos) to AWS S3 storage. This works like a charm.

However, due to the large amount of upload time it takes to upload a video to AWS S3 Storage, I'm trying to find a solution to retrieve the upload progress statistics e.g. uploadedBytes & totalBytesToUpload to calculate the time remaining until a video upload has been completed.

I've searched through dozen of StackOverflow questions and blogs on the internet on how to retrieve these statistics real-time of an uploading file, but haven't found a working solution.

What have I tried?

#### Original code

```
$result = $this->s3Client->createMultipartUpload([
            'Bucket'       => $this->bucket,
            'Key'          => $path,
            'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD',
            'ACL'          => 'public-read',
            'Metadata'     => $metaDataValues
        ]);
```

#### Code using @http progress (GuzzleHttp) (found on https://stackoverflow.com/a/43700547/4686900)

```
$result = $this->s3Client->createMultipartUpload([
            'Bucket'       => $this->bucket,
            'Key'          => $path,
            'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD',
            'ACL'          => 'public-read',
            'Metadata'     => $metaDataValues,
            '@http' => [
                'progress' => function ($downloadTotalSize, $downloadSizeSoFar, $uploadTotalSize, $uploadSizeSoFar) {
                    $this->loggerService->logError("down [" . $downloadSizeSoFar ."]/[".$downloadTotalSize."] up [".$uploadSizeSoFar."]/[".$uploadTotalSize."]");
                }
            ]
        ]);
```

This code logs the following output after uploading a video to AWS S3 Storage

```
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [0]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [0]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [0]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [0]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [0]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [0]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [0]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [0]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [0]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [435]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [435]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [435]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [435]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [435]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
[2020-09-29 16:29:45] customLog.ERROR: down [435]/[0] up [0]/[0] [] []
```

In the logs you see that *up* stats [0]/[0], so no changes.

I've tried to think of other solutions such as calculating uploadedBytes using JavaScript AJAX XHR function, see code:

```
$.ajax(
{
//...
xhr: function() {
      let xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
           let percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
           console.log(percentComplete)
        }
      }, false);
  return xhr;
}
// ...
});
```

This code, however, only captures the amount of bytes transfered between me locally and our own server, and not between my local environment & the AWS S3 Storage server.

#### Complete code

```
public function uploadMultipart($file, $path, $metaDataValues = [])
{
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

        $parts = array();
        $result = $this->s3Client->createMultipartUpload([
            'Bucket'       => $this->bucket,
            'Key'          => $path,
            'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD',
            'ACL'          => 'public-read',
            'Metadata'     => $metaDataValues,
            '@http' => [
                'progress' => function ($downloadTotalSize, $downloadSizeSoFar, $uploadTotalSize, $uploadSizeSoFar) {
                    $this->loggerService->logError("down [" . $downloadSizeSoFar ."]/[".$downloadTotalSize."] up [".$uploadSizeSoFar."]/[".$uploadTotalSize."]");
                }
            ]
        ]);

        $uploadId = $result['UploadId'];

        // Upload the file in parts.
        try
        {
            $file = fopen($file, 'r');
            $partNumber = 1;

            while (!feof($file))
            {
                $result = $this->s3Client->uploadPart([
                    'Bucket'     => $this->bucket,
                    'Key'        => $path,
                    'UploadId'   => $uploadId,
                    'PartNumber' => $partNumber,
                    'Body'       => fread($file, 500 * 1024 * 1024),
                ]);

                $parts['Parts'][$partNumber] = [
                    'PartNumber' => $partNumber,
                    'ETag' => $result['ETag'],
                ];

                $partNumber++;
            }
            fclose($file);
        }
        catch (S3Exception $e) {
            $this->s3Client->abortMultipartUpload([
                'Bucket'   => $this->bucket,
                'Key'      => $path,
                'UploadId' => $uploadId
            ]);

            $this->logger->error("Error multipart uploading: " . $e->getMessage() . " on " . $e->getLine() . " for " . $e->getFile());
        }

        // Complete the multipart upload.
        $result = $this->s3Client->completeMultipartUpload([
            'Bucket'   => $this->bucket,
            'Key'      => $path,
            'UploadId' => $uploadId,
            'MultipartUpload' => $parts,
        ]);

        return $result['Location'];
}
```

### Question

How can I retrieve the amount of uploaded bytes & total bytes to upload using the S3 createMultipartUpload function or alternative ways, between my local system & the AWS S3 Storage server.

*p.s. I'm using PHP 7.2.20, Symfony 3.4 & AWS SDK for PHP v3*

Comment: Did you check this out https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/785#issuecomment-146722554?